# Convert python pandas dataframe rows or columns into numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a data frame like this. [from csv file]

```
       l1  p1 p2 p3 ... p10
    0   ↑  ←---- rows ----→
    1   |  ←---- rows ----→
    2   c  ←---- rows ----→
    3   o  ←---- rows ----→
    .   l  ←---- rows ----→
    .   |  ←---- rows ----→
    9   ↓  ←---- rows ----→
```

I want to convert **l1** column into numpy array like this
`[ ←, -, c, o, l, -, →] size : 10`

and all the remaining columns into another numpy array like this\

```
[[ ← - r o w s - →],
 [ ← - r o w s - →],
 [ ← - r o w s - →]]    size: (10, 10)
```

---

**Also**

---

columns in the data frame are images so how can I further divide my data frame like this

```
           l1   p1 p2 .... p784
    0       ↑  ←---- rows ----→
    1       |  ←---- rows ----→
    2       c  ←---- rows ----→
    3       o  ←---- rows ----→
    .       l  ←---- rows ----→
    .       |  ←---- rows ----→
    27455   ↓  ←---- rows ----→
```

After getting the rows array on this data frame
I will have numpy array of `size(27455, 784)`
How to further split this array into `size(27455, 28, 28)`

how to do this !!
any other way will also be appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
col=df.l1.to_numpy()

ary=df.drop('l1',axis=1).to_numpy()
```

Comment: I was about to accept your answer than system said to wait for 7 min !! Than I was editing the question and here I am ...

Comment: @Manan `df.drop('l1',axis=1).to_numpy().reshape(len(df),-1,28).shape` for you update question

Comment: (o_ _)ﾉ彡☆ Nice !!